# How to copy column header from SQL Server to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

When I copy and paste output from SQL Server to Excel, I want column headers to be pasted. However, sometimes it fails. Has anyone experienced this issue? And how should I fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you click on `copy with header`?

Comment: If you use Microsoft SQL Management you can right click and choose the option to "Copy with headers". Ctrl + Shift + C is the default command.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Thanks

Comment: @Wizhi Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)... Choose "Edit" > "Copy With Headers"

Answer (score 0):

Right click and select `copy with headers`.
This should copy the data along with the headers which can be pasted in excel